# creating seed data for a model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a question model that belongs to User. Initially, I'd like to set basic questions with an attribute public: true, and every user can see this kind of questions which I'd like to create in the seed.rb.

Then, subsequently with an Answer model. Each users answer belongs to a certain question.

Now the issue is creating these pre-made questions for the users to answer I've tried the following in seed.rb:

```
u = User.new(email: "test@gmail.com", password: "testpass", password_confirmation: "testpass", gender: "M")
questions = u.questions.build(title: "What is your favourite food?")
u.save
```

And I'd like to call the same default questions for all users in the view with

questions_controller.rb

```
def index 
  @questions = Question.all
end
```

But this simply doesn't seem to be working, i.e. when I go to rails c and run u, it's an undefined method.. and the u.questions is an empty array. I've run these lines in console manually and they worked so I'm not sure what's happening here.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update dev log**

```
    ^[[1m^[[36mUser Load (16.9ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35mQuestion Load (645.9ms)^[[0m  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
  ^[[1m^[[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (48.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35m (0.3ms)^[[0m  BEGIN
  ^[[1m^[[36mUser Exists (34.7ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'anthony@gmail.com' LIMIT 1^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35m (0.3ms)^[[0m  ROLLBACK
DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from service a\
t /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138)
```

Comment: When you say you "run u", do you mean you do:  `u = User.first`?

Comment: CDub, correct -  u = User.first then u.questions = empty array. Something wrong with seed data.

Comment: `u = User.first` shouldn't return an empty array... It should return either a `User` object or nil.  Have you run `rake db:seed`?

Comment: thanks Cdub, sorry I edited it I ran u = User.first then u.questions and it was an empty array, and yep I ran rake db:seed

Comment: What does `log/development.log` show when you run `rake db:seed`?

Comment: Updated with dev log, doesn't say much though unfortunately.

Comment: That doesn't show the results of `rake db:seed`...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42357/discussion-between-cdub-and-sonny-black)

Comment: Change `u.save` to `u.save!` so we can see if there is validation exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue was that the OP had bad data in the development database.

Running `rake db:drop db:create db:setup` appeared to fix the issue.